# Cube.js: Can't find join path to join

Tags: sql, mongodb, cube.js

I'm taking over a website. I could not reach the previous developer anymore. He decided to use cube.js and once showed me a working KPI page with charts. Now, I'm trying to make the page work on my side, and understand what he did.

I have installed cube.js on my machine. The collections in our database are `comments`, `folders`, `logs`, `posts`, `sessions`, `subscribers`, `users`. I used `cubejs generate -t users` and `cubejs generate -t logs` to generate `Users.js` and `Logs.js`. For example, here is the generated `Users.js`:

```
cube(`Users`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM news.users`,

  joins: {

  },

  measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`,
      drillMembers: [currentname, currentprovider, googleJsonDisplayname, googleJsonId, googleJsonNameFamilyname, googleJsonNameGivenname, googleDisplayname, googleId, googleNameFamilyname, googleNameGivenname, googleProvider, localId, localProvider, firstdate]
    },

    googleJsonCircledbycount: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.circledByCount\``,
      type: `sum`,
      title: `Google. Json.circledbycount`
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
    currentname: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`currentName\``,
      type: `string`
    },

    currentprovider: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`currentProvider\``,
      type: `string`
    },

    firstapp: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`firstApp\``,
      type: `string`
    },

    googleJsonDisplayname: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.displayName\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.displayname`
    },

    googleJsonEtag: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.etag\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.etag`
    },

    googleJsonGender: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.gender\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.gender`
    },

    googleJsonId: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.id\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.id`
    },

    googleJsonImageUrl: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.image.url\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.image.url`
    },

    googleJsonKind: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.kind\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.kind`
    },

    googleJsonLanguage: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.language\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.language`
    },

    googleJsonNameFamilyname: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.name.familyName\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.name.familyname`
    },

    googleJsonNameGivenname: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.name.givenName\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.name.givenname`
    },

    googleJsonObjecttype: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.objectType\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.objecttype`
    },

    googleJsonUrl: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._json.url\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Json.url`
    },

    googleRaw: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google._raw\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google. Raw`
    },

    googleDisplayname: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google.displayName\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google.displayname`
    },

    googleGender: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google.gender\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google.gender`
    },

    googleId: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google.id\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google.id`
    },

    googleNameFamilyname: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google.name.familyName\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google.name.familyname`
    },

    googleNameGivenname: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google.name.givenName\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google.name.givenname`
    },

    googleProvider: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`google.provider\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Google.provider`
    },

    localExpired: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`local.expired\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Local.expired`
    },

    localFirstapp: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`local.firstApp\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Local.firstapp`
    },

    localHash: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`local.hash\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Local.hash`
    },

    localId: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`local.id\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Local.id`
    },

    localProvider: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`local.provider\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Local.provider`
    },

    localSalt: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`local.salt\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Local.salt`
    },

    localType: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`local.type\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Local.type`
    },

    localVerificationcode: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`local.verificationCode\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Local.verificationcode`
    },

    localVerified: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`local.verified\``,
      type: `string`,
      title: `Local.verified`
    },

    firstdate: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`firstDate\``,
      type: `time`
    }
  }
});
```

Then, I launched cube.js backend and his page `localhost:8000/kpi` on my machine. There are errors like `Error: Error: Cube 'Customs' not found for path 'Customs.count'`, `Error: Error: Cube 'Customs' not found for path 'Customs.count'` and `Error: Error: Can't find join path to join 'Users', 'Logs'`:

[image]

Here is how the previous developer defined his `query.ts`:

```
export const getQueryUserByType = (dateRange: any, granularity: any) => ({
  measures: ['Users.count'],
  dimensions: ['Users.localType'],
  timeDimensions: dateRange
    ? [
        {
          dimension: 'Logs.date',
          dateRange: dateRange,
          granularity,
        },
      ]
    : [
        {
          dimension: 'Logs.date',
          granularity,
        },
      ],
});

export const getQueryUserPageVist = (dateRange: any, granularity: any) => ({
  measures: ['Users.count'],
  dimensions: ['Logs.url'],
  timeDimensions: dateRange
    ? [
        {
          dimension: 'Logs.date',
          dateRange: dateRange,
          granularity,
        },
      ]
    : [
        {
          dimension: 'Logs.date',
          granularity,
        },
      ],
  filters: [
    {
      member: 'Logs.actionThetype',
      operator: 'equals',
      values: ['VisitPage'],
    },
  ],
});

export const getQueryCustomByApp = (dateRange: any, granularity: any) => ({
  measures: ['Customs.count'],
  dimensions: ['Customs.offerdisplayname'],
  timeDimensions: dateRange
    ? [
        {
          dimension: 'Customs.timestamp',
          dateRange: dateRange,
          granularity,
        },
      ]
    : [
        {
          dimension: 'Customs.timestamp',
          granularity,
        },
      ],
});
```

Could anyone tell What errors like `Error: Error: Cube 'Customs' not found for path 'Customs.count'`, `Error: Error: Cube 'Customs' not found for path 'Customs.count'` and `Error: Error: Can't find join path to join 'Users', 'Logs'` mean? How could I fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is missing Cube.js schema which is essential part of Cube.js deployment. You either should try to find this missing source code or redevelop it based on your dashboard ui application.

As errors state you're missing `Customs` cube definition as well as join definition between `Users` and `Logs`. You can learn more about joins here: https://cube.dev/docs/joins

Comment: I'm also seeing an error like this: `Cube 'Test' not found for path 'Test.transactionCount'`.  This means that Cube can't find the schema files in the image?  Where is it looking for these files?

Comment: In my case, I've put the files in `/cube/conf/schema`.  Where else would they go?  This is `schema` appended to the `WORKDIR` of the cubejs/cube image.  Documentation states that the default of `CUBEJS_SCHEMA_PATH` is `schema` (which, as an aside is not correct -- this variable is empty if not set).